# React-Redux: Pass status to inner containers

Tags: reactjs, redux

May seem like a simple question but after several days I still find no answer.

The case is that I have a simple application that I connect through the functions of Redux. The structure would look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And then in the App component is where I have my routes:

```
export class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isLoginPage: PropTypes.bool,
    activeMenu: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div >
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={ publicPath } component={ Authorization(Timesheet) } />
                <Route path={ routeCodes.LOGIN } component={ Login } />
                <Route path={ routeCodes.SETTINGS } component={ Authorization(Settings) } />
                <Route path='*' component={ NotFound } />
              </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLoginPage: state.login.get('isLoginPage'),
    activeMenu: state.menu.get('activeMenu'),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(App);
```

My problem is, that if I create another component and insert it into one of those, for example, within Timesheet, that component, for whatever reason, does not connect.

An example component I use would be:

```
export class Menu extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // from react-redux connect
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.openMenu = this.openMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeMenu: false,
    }
  }

  openMenu() {
    debugger;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Menu2
        <button onClick={this.openMenu}>button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Menu.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogout: state.menu.get('isLogout'),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  {
    pure: false,
  }
)(Menu);
```

If I add the component within Timesheet, it never goes through the mapStateToProps function, however if I put it inside the App, this way:
    render() {
            return (
              
                
                
                      
                        
                        
                        
                        
                      
                
              
            );
          }
This works perfectly, is connected, and every time the state changes, it goes through the mapStateToProps function of the Menu component.

Do you think it may be happening or missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: your mapStateToProps in the Menu example really doesnt do anything? It should be wrapped with connect in your export ?

Comment: it is wrapped with connect, because, it is the way to connect this isolated component to the application, isnt it?

Comment: my bad, a scrolling malfunction at my part within your code-snippet :)

Comment: Would be nice to see what your store looks like. Havent seen using a function like state.menu.get('someprop') approach before. Normally you just bind it directly to a given property. Like state.menu.someprop

Comment: I bet someting is wrong with your Authorization wrapper. Could you please provide us with its sources?

Comment: I remove the Authorization wrapper, but it keeps not working.

Comment: I just upload the source code, here: https://bitbucket.org/_nitsuga_/novatracker/src

Comment: I just discover where is the problem. When a Import the component I was using so:
import {MonthSelector} from '../../components/MonthSelector';

but I should use this:
import MonthSelector from '../../components/MonthSelector';

With this, it is working. Although I am receiving this error from eslint:

[eslint] Using exported name 'MonthSelector' as identifier for default export. (import/no-named-as-default)